# Angularjs ng-repeat does not work if div is moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

in angularJS I am using ng-repeat to build an list of items. The list is initially in a popup created through kendoui's window. There is a requirement that the popup should be pinnable so I am moving the contents of the div to another div. Works perfectly till now.

After I refresh the array bound with ng-repeat through an ajax call the list becomes empty.

I have created a simple fiddle to show that ng-repeat stops working if div is moved. In the fiddle there is no ajax call so the list does not get empty.

Html:

```
    <p>
        <button ng-click="AddInArray()">Add</button>
    </p>
    <div id="lblDiv">
        <label ng-repeat="item in itemsArray | orderBy:'toString()'">{{item}}-{{$index}}:</label>
    </div>
    <button id="btn" ng-click="btn_click()">Move</button>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.itemsArray = ["Test"];

$scope.AddInArray = function() {
   this.itemsArray.push("Test");  
}

$scope.btn_click = function() {
   var html = $("#lblDiv").html();
   $("#container").html(html);
   $("#lblDiv").html("");
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7859/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kutyel/HB7LU/7861/).

Basically, you had to change this:

```
$scope.btn_click= function(){
    var html = $("#lblDiv");
    $("#container").append(html);
    $("#lblDiv").remove(html);
};
```

Or, which is just the same, but in one line:

```
$("#lblDiv").appendTo("#container");
```

Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You've emptied the template.

```
$("#lblDiv").html("");
```

Should be:

```
$scope.itemsArray = ["Test"];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/HB7LU/7860/)

If you want to actually move the div replace the entire function with:

```
$("#lblDiv").appendTo("#container");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jonathan_Ironman/HB7LU/7862/)

Comment: thats the original container. I have moved stuff form lblDiv to container. Please check out fiddle

Comment: You're moving the result HTML, not the template.

Comment: How do I move the template?

Answer (score 0):

Add this one it might help you

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    //myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
    //myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Superhero';
        $scope.itemsArray = ["Test"];

        $scope.AddInArray = function() {
          this.itemsArray.push("Test");  
        };
        $scope.btn_click= function(){
    var html = $("#lblDiv");
            $("#container").html(html);
            $("#lblDiv").append("");
        };

}
```